# Will Facebook scope id duplicate?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two apps, `A` and `B`, they both share the same account database, With new Facebook policy, I will get different scope id from different apps, Facebook has `ids_for_business` can check, if I add app `C`, there will be a new scope id and login, I can use `ids_for_business` to check if I if use have scope id already exists in account database, then use that one to login, he can get all his record, but will scope id duplicate among apps? for example app `A` have scope id 123456 and app `C` also have scope id 123456, will it happen?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$id = 'xxxx';
$secret = 'xxxx';
$url = 'url';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($url);

try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['access_token']);
    } else {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    }
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($ex->getMessage()); echo '</pre>';
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($ex->getMessage()); echo '</pre>';
}

if ($session) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $session->getToken();
    $request = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/ids_for_business'))->execute();
    $idGroup = (array)$request->getGraphObject()->getProperty('data')->asArray();
    $userId = current($idGroup)->id;
    $request = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $userId))->execute();
    $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    // Todo: Check if user has scope id in data base by $idGroup
    // if none register new one
    // if yes login with that scope id
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">go</a>';
}
```

Comment: please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: ok, I put my sample code, although the question is not about the code

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

Answer (score 0):

App Scoped IDs are globally unique. App Scoped ID for your App A and App C will not be the same.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading
"The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps"